# NSArray valueForKey returning NSNull?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsarray

Given the following code (uses magicrecord for the coredata fetching):

```
// Get all of our apps.
NSArray * applications = [Application MR_findAllInContext: [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]];

Application * application = [applications firstObject];
NSLog(@"Test: %@", application.applicationId);

NSArray * applicationIds = [applications valueForKey: @"applicationId"];
NSLog(@"Application ids: %@", applicationIds);
```

I get the following logs:

```
Test: 586001240
Application ids: (
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
```

I know that the `applications` array contains two entries. Each has a unique `applicationId` property. I don't understand why the call to `valueForKey` is returning me two nulls? Instead I should be getting two NSNumber objects.

I recently found out about valueForKey (previously to get unique entries I would use an enumeration and add the entries to an array). I'm trying to use valueForKey to improve the readability. Obviously I am not understanding something correctly. Any tips on where I am going wrong?

Edit - More details:

The `Application` class is generated via a core data model. The interface is defined as:

```
@interface Application : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * applicationId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@end
```

Comment: I think you want to use a `NSDictionary`? I also think that the valueForKey: method belongs to KVO and can not be used like you do it

Comment: What's the interface like for `Application`? Is it Key Value compliant?

Comment: The code you have looks fine, so we'd need to see the implementation and declaration of the Application.applicationId property. If it's just a standard core data property, there may be a problem with faulting.

Comment: Thanks guys. Figured it out and posted an answer. The problem was that I was using `MR_context` as my context instead of `MR_defaultContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - Very dumb problem on my end.

I had to change:

`[Application MR_findAllInContext: [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]];`

To be:

`[Application MR_findAllInContext: [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];`

That solved the issue.

Comment: For others to learn from (as `MR_defaultContext` is your own method), what was the root cause of the problem, considering that `Application * application = [applications firstObject];` worked?